# cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1",param1 ?? DbNull.Value)

Tags: c#, sql, dbnull

I have int? type value which can be either null or have some value. I want to execute a insert statement using parametrized query to insert accordingly.

```
int? val1=null; 
SqlCeCommand cmd;
string insert = "insert into table(col1)values(@col_1)";
cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
cmd.CommandText = insert;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_1", val1 ?? Convert.ToInt32(DBNull.Value)));
cmd.Connection = cn1;
cn1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn1.Close();
```

This code throws format exception error. I even tried

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_1", (!val1.HasValue) ? val1 : Convert.ToInt32(DBNull.Value));
```

How shld it b done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to convert if null set `DBNull`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_1", (object)val1 ??DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would believe that changing the line to the following should work:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_1", val1 ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Since this would set the parameter value to an object type.

If that fails for some reason try to cast the result to an object like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_1", (object)(val1 ?? DBNull.Value));
```

But this should not be necessary.

Edit:
Actually, this should work:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_1", val1 ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: I get this error : Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: @user1650891 how about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807229/cmd-parameters-addwithvalueparam1-param1-dbnull-value/16807294#16807294)

Comment: @user1650891 Just updated my answer, you must cast the DBNull.Value to an object. Then it shoulw work fine

Answer (score 0):

You Should change add parameter code like this:

```
if (val1.HasValue)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_1", val1.Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col_1", DBNull.Value);
}
```